# ZF2 Mock crashes on undefined method

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework

I'm following [this tutorial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#configuring-the-service-manager-for-the-tests) for unit testing on ZF2. I'm familiar with unit testing, so I pretty much understand what's going on.

I'm getting a `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_AlbumTable_9fb22412::fetchAll() in [my controller's route here]`.

If I'm following correctly, the controller calls `fetchAll` on my mock object. The weird part is why is it undefined, if I declared it in the mock expectations.

My test code is exactly the same on the link provided, (Literally copy/pasted), and my `AlbumTable` class is also from the tutorial:

```
<?php

namespace Album\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AlbumTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

    // ... more code ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit:** visiting said controller's route from the web browser works, so it's not an issue with the `AlbumTable` class, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

You miss this line:

```
$albumTableMock=$this->getMockBuilder('Album\Model\AlbumTable')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(array('fetchAll'))  // <- you miss this line
    ->getMock();
```